# how to get url of app in django

Tags: python, django, url

how can I get the URL path for App

```
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    # path defined for the app in the projects urls.py
    return HttpResponseRedirect('??????')
```

I know I can hard code it but how can I get it?

urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^chat/',include('djangoChat.urls')),
```

djangoChat.urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$',views.login,name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.logout,name='logout')
)
```

i want logout method to redirect to `/chat` path 
so views.index method gets called

Comment: What url are you trying to retrieve? Could you post your `urls.py` file and identify the specific url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse lookup a URL by name, do:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Comment: Just a note to the user , you will have to use named urls for this